# Difference between URLConnection getInputStream() & HttpEntity getContent()

Tags: android, inputstream

I try to download pic from the specific url, firstly I use this way to get InputStream:

```
if (url != null) {
            URLConnection ucon = null;
            try {
                ucon = url.openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (ucon != null) {
                ucon.setConnectTimeout(CONN_TIMEOUT);
                ucon.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                try {
                    is = ucon.getInputStream();
```

It works good, but when I try to download pic from http://111.12.12.232/images/face/bigface/339.gif
I can't get the InputStream, but try to use :

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8");

            HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, false);
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, CONN_TIMEOUT);

            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, READ_TIMEOUT);
            HttpGet getRequest;
            try {
                getRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
```

This way can get InputStream successfully, and can download the gif.

So I wonder what's the different between the two methods?
Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

It [looks like](http://hurl.it/hurls/8020c9be29d82d7b31c2ac0b569a69deb4f6b784/1061f6b4b1ee1f7a966a9c6e0900d95bcecdf3dc) the server returns the image content but also returns a 404 response code, which indicates an error fulfilling the request.

On the [1.6 Sun/Oracle JDK](http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/), the HttpURLConnection seems to fail with an IOException when it notices a return code like this, and does not attempt to return content.  My guess is that the Android platform has this same behavior, and the Apache HttpClient library you used is a bit more robust to server misconfigurations.